# Call methods in other windows when viewmodel variable changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window called `Timeline` (not my mainwindow), that can be opened several times with different values being passed. What I'm trying to do is, when a certain value is changed in my viewmodel for my main window, I want to call a method in each `Timeline` window that is open.

Here's the variable that is constantly changing. When it does change, I want to call the testDraw() function (also in the viewmodel).

```
private int _currentIteration;
public int CurrentIteration //used to hold current index of the list of data fields
{
    get { return _currentIteration; }
    set
    {
        _currentIteration = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIteration");
    }
}

//Want to call this when CurrentIteration changes
public void testDraw()
{
    foreach (Timeline timeLineWin in Application.Current.Windows)
    {   
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            timeLineWin.setCurrentValues(CurrentIteration);
            timeLineWin.linechart1.HighlightPoint(timeLineWin.currentX, timeLineWin.currentY);
        }));
        //linechart1 is a winforms component on the timeline window   
    }            
}
```

Here's the code behind for the timeline window:

```
public partial class Timeline : Window
{
    public List<double> xValues;
    public List<double> yValues;
    public double currentX;
    public double currentY;

    public Timeline(List<double> x, List<double> y)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        xValues = x;
        yValues = y;
    }

    public void setCurrentValues(int i)
    {
        currentX = xValues[i];
        currentY = yValues[i];
    }
}
```

The function 'testDraw()' is supposed to loop through all the currently open `Timeline` windows and call the two functions in those windows.

The error I got was:

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` - So I tried using `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the method which also did not work.

Note: I wasn't sure how to keep this bit in the MVVM format.

Comment: Can you post the `StackTrace` of your `InvalidOperationException`? It should be pretty easy to find the culprit there.

Comment: StackTrace: "   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()\r\n   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()\r\n   at System.Windows.Application.get_Windows()" string

Comment: Update my 'TestDraw' function to show the dispatcher I was trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke your whole `testDraw` method in the `Dispatcher` because even the getter of `Application.Current.Windows` requires it:

```
public void testDraw()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        foreach (Timeline timeLineWin in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            timeLineWin.setCurrentValues(CurrentIteration);
            timeLineWin.linechart1
                .HighlightPoint(timeLineWin.currentX, timeLineWin.currentY);
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: Getting this error - "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type". What would the delegate method be inside of the `Invoke`? Action?

Comment: @pfinferno `Dispatcher.Invoke()` was extended in .net 4.5 to not only support a `Delegate` but also an `Action` parameter. I edited my answer to reflect that so it does compile if you are using a .net framework before 4.5.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using 4.0. Marking your answer.  I'm having an InvalidCastException now though, maybe you could help? It's highlighting `timeLineWin` in the foreach loop, saying can't cast `Project1.MainWindow` to `Project1.Timeline`. Any idea why? I get the same thing if I do `foreach (Timeserver.Timeline timeLineWin in Application.Current.Windows)`

Comment: @pfinferno If you have other types of windows you can filter them using LINQ: `Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Timeline>()`. Aside from that - you're very welcome, glad I could help you!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using the EventAggregator for communicating between windows? There is an option for subscribign on the user interface thread: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

When you construct each time line object subscribe to the

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<IterationChangeEvent>().Subscribe(UpdateUI, ThreadOption.UIThread);

private void UpdateUI(Iteration iteration)
{
    this.setCurrentValues(iteration);
    this.linechart1.HighlightPoint(this.currentX, this.currentY);
}
```

In your main window when the CurrentIteration changes call:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<IterationChangeEvent>().Publish(this.currentIteration);
```

Your event class would lool something like this:

```
public class IterationChangeEvent : CompositeWpfEvent<int>
{
}
```

Comment: I certainly could be wrong but I think `.Subscribe(UpdateUI)` should be `.Subscribe(UpdateUI, ThreadOption.UIThread)` to avoid the `InvalidOperationException` of the OP because the default value is just `ThreadOption.PublisherThread` as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405768(v=pandp.40).aspx). It could also be possible that each window has its own dispatcher, which means that you have to invoke the action in the correct dispatcher manually. (But of course the whole thing should be done using MVVM anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, @haindl I've updated the code and added a reference.

Comment: I will test this out now! I would love to do this the MVVM way btw, just not sure how to loop through open windows while keeping the VM seperate from the view.

Comment: The EventAggregator is a common pattern that is used with MVVM so your code will still be MVVM. You don't need to loop through the VMs, that's kinda the point. You simply publish a single event. Every subscriber that you set up will receive the event.

Comment: @openshac Even if you use an `EventAggregator` it would surely be a better solution to update the underlying `ViewModel` (which the control is data-bound to) in the subscription and not the `linechart1` control directly. (At least if you want to do it in an MVVM way.)

Comment: Yes exactly, unfortunately the original OP doesn't have a TimeLine VM, the TimeLine class is a window.

Comment: Saving this answer for later, hopefully I can get around to converting the rest of this to fit the MVVM way. Thanks again